# Why would number properties be missing from a Web API post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm posting content to a Web API endpoint. The string properties are posting fine, but any number properties are coming in with a default value instead of the posted value.

My endpoint looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{dealKey:int}/materialsView")]
public PagedResources<MaterialsViewRow> GetMaterialsView(int dealKey, SearchCriteria criteria)
{
    return _service.GetMaterialsView(dealKey, criteria);
}
```

And my criteria object has many properties, such as these:

```
public int? Offset { get; set; }
public int? PageSize { get; set; }
public string Sort { get; set; }
public bool? SortDescending { get; set; }
```

The "Sort" property, for example, receives the string value just fine, but the numeric properties such as "Offset" and "PageSize" are null. DealKey, however, which is a URL parameter does work.

Here in Chrome, I can see the "pageSize" value being sent.

[image: Request Payload]

But it is not getting set correctly on the server like the string properties are.

[image: Server]

Here's the raw post captured by Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:64021/api/marketinglists/4395/materialsView?v=1.35 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:64021
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 349
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Negotiate [clipped for brevity]=
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:64021
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:64021/deals/@TST9%7CD/marketingList
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=[clipped for brevity];

{"isBusy":true,"searchText":"","isInitial":false,"offset":0,"pageSize":30,"sort":"companyName","dealKey":4395}
```

Comment: Reference [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: What does your POST request look like?  Not a picture of it, the _actual_ request

Comment: @maccettura, I updated the question with the POST request.

Comment: @adam0101 - good point.

Comment: Try using `[FromBody]` on `criteria` parameter. i.e: `GetMaterialsView(int dealKey, [FromBody]SearchCriteria criteria)`

Comment: Can we see the full `SearchCriteria` class?  Including constructors or any default member initialization.  I wonder if Igor is on to something and the string properties working is a red herring

Comment: You also have dealKey defined in the body, what happens when remove in param list

Comment: Unbelievable. On a hunch, I rebooted my computer and it started working. Something must have gotten corrupt in Visual Studio or IIS Express, but it's working now. Thanks to all who helped.